# Difference Between Modulus Implementation in Python Vs Java

Tags: java, python, modulo

I've noticed differing implementations of the modulus operator in Python and Java.

For example, in Python:

```
>>> print -300 % 800
>>> 500
```

Whereas in Java:

```
System.out.println(-300 % 800);
-300
```

This caught me off guard, since I thought something as basic as modulus was universally interpreted the same way. I'm a fan of Python's interpretation (which I presume is borrowed from C), although I see the logic behind Java's implementation.

Which do you typically prefer? Is there any specific reason for the differing interpretations? I have no intention of starting a language war, simply curious.

Comment: If I'm reading the Wikipedia page that Alex posted correctly, Python's math.fmod would return the same result as Java's mod.

Comment: The best way to avoid language wars is to only talk about one language at a time. If there's another plausible way that something could or should work, it is *not necessary and often not helpful* to appeal to "but this other language does it the other way" - instead, explain the thought process behind that interpretation, directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer C's interpretation (also used in Python), where `%` is indeed a modulus operator.  Good discussion in the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) and the links from it (including one bit about why taking instead the sign of the dividend can lead to one silly bug unless one's careful;-).

Comment: C99 uses the sign of the dividend, C89 is implemention dependent, at least according to the article you linked.

Comment: You can use `%` in Java to write a function that does the same thing as Python; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3417242/320036

Comment: C behaves like Java, not Python.

Answer (score 4):

Now try this:

```
>>> print 300 % -800
-500
```

The reason for the difference is that language designers can't seem to decide whether the remainder after division should have the sign of the *dividend* or the *divisor*.  Some languages don't even specify one or the other, so it's up to the implementer.

There's a list of languages, the operator, and which sign to expect on the [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) Wikipedia page.  It's a good place to start, but I usually just run a few simple tests to make sure I know exactly how `%` is going to behave before I use it in any language I've not tested it in before.

Answer (score 1):

In the C standard, negative modulo is undefined, and many C compilers will give you what Java is giving you. In python though, you will always get a positive number, which is often more useful, because it means you can do modulo addition, and subtraction. If negative modulo were to give you a negative, it would not work properly.

I have no idea what advantages getting a negative number from a modulo has.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `x mod n` to give numbers between 0 and n-1 or between floor(n/2)-n and floor(n/2); this makes it easiest to do the math in one's head.

As long as everything is equivalent, I don't really care when it comes to languages--though one does have to be aware of the convention.

Incidentally, Java can't quite make up its mind--% on negative integers returns a negative value, the `mod` method of `java.math.BigInteger` returns values between 0 and n-1 (inclusive), and the `divideAndRemainder` method again returns negative values for negative integers.