# Modulo of negative numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, modulo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mod of negative number is melting my brain!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain)

I was wondering if there was a nicer algorithm for what I'm trying to do:

```
wrapIndex(-6, 3) = 0
wrapIndex(-5, 3) = 1
wrapIndex(-4, 3) = 2
wrapIndex(-3, 3) = 0
wrapIndex(-2, 3) = 1
wrapIndex(-1, 3) = 2
wrapIndex(0, 3) = 0
wrapIndex(1, 3) = 1
wrapIndex(2, 3) = 2
wrapIndex(3, 3) = 0
wrapIndex(4, 3) = 1
wrapIndex(5, 3) = 2
```

I came up with

```
function wrapIndex(i, i_max) {
        if(i > -1)
            return i%i_max;

        var x = i_max + i%i_max;
        if(x == i_max)
            return 0;

        return x;
    }
```

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Mod of negative number is melting my brain! ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain) and of at least a dozen questions on this website. :-)

Comment: Well, I searched for modulo of negative numbers and didn't really find anything... Sorry for another duplicate.

Comment: `int mod(int k, int n) {  return ((k %= n) < 0) ? k+n : k;  }`

Comment: And in Python `(k % n)` is always positive if `n` is positive.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This solution is branchless, but performs `%` twice:

```
function wrapIndex(i, i_max) {
   return ((i % i_max) + i_max) % i_max;
}
```

It should be said the C#/Java behavior of `%` is assumed, i.e. the result has the same sign as the *dividend*. Some languages define the remainder calculation to take the sign of the *divisor* instead (e.g. `mod` in Clojure). Some languages have both variants (`mod`/`rem` pair in Common Lisp, Haskell, etc). Algol-68 has `%x` which always returns a non-negative number. C++ left it up to implementation until C++11, [now the sign of the remainder is (almost) fully specified according to the dividend sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100711/operator-modulo-change-in-c-11).

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: +1 because it actually works. ;-)

Comment: Version with a branch returns i_max for negative multiple of i_max

Comment: @Maciej: You're right; taking it out completely (since I'm not a fan of it anyway; was just trying to be "complete").

Answer (score 10):

The solution with two `%` operations works, but this is somewhat faster in most languages on most hardware (there are exceptions, however):

```
int wrapIndex(int i, int i_max) {
    i = i%i_max;
    return i<0 ? i+i_max : i;
}
```

Comment: Wait, branch is faster than 2x %? Hard to believe.

Answer (score 5):

Nicer is a matter of taste, but How about

```
var x = (i_max + i % i_max) % i_max;
```

Comment: I really feel uncomfortable upvoting this, since I don't know the exact operation precedence rules for Java, or whatever language this question is asked for, but I'm sure you know what you're doing (thanks for the correction, I see that at least 3 people including me has made that error here already)

Comment: @polygenelubricants: `%` has precedence over `+` in essentially all modern languages.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
function wrapIndex(i, i_max) {
    if (i < 0) i = (i % i_max) + i_max;
    return i % i_max;
}
```

Comment: Previous version was correct :) (i % i_max) + i_max may be equal i_max if (i % i_max) == 0

Comment: @Maciej Hehl: Dammit, you’re right.

Answer (score 2):

Many users gave good answers, just beware negative numbers, since different languages may behave differently.
By example this C snippet writes "-1"

```
int main ()
{
    printf("%d\n", (-4) % 3);
}
```

While in python we have a different output value

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:43:55) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> (-4) % 3
2
```

**EDIT**: Actually I don't think you'll have negative indexes! However it's good to know that.